# Field-of-view effect on iPhone 7 using structure-from-motion

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Now that the iPhone 7 Plus has two camera lenses to increase optical zoom, it can also create a depth map between two images. This allows it to create a simulated field-of-view effect (Blurred Background behind person or object).

Would it be possible to capture two images from slightly different focal points on the single lense iPhone 7? The user would be required to move the camera slightly to produce the second image.

Once the software has two images can a depth map be created in xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create a depth map from two images. OpenCV has some useful [functions](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html)

But if you have two images taken in sequence you have to align them perfectly first.